# Recent insights on algorithms for 1D bin packing

Tags: ds.algorithms, co.combinatorics, approximation-algorithms, time-complexity

This is just a general question on recent algorithms for the 1D bin packing problem. I just want to collect some information on this issue, so I’m grateful for any information. Especially heuristics solving the problem but also exact algorithms.

I know about the Bin Completion algorithm by Korf and the recent developments in Branch-and-Price algorithms. But is there anything else? As said before, I’m grateful for any information.

Comment: Are you interested in approximation algorithms? Thomas Rotvhoss recently showed how to compute a solution that uses at most $OPT + O(\log OPT \log \log OPT)$ number of bins in polynomial time.

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly the kind of information I'm looking for.